# How to present a UiView from a SKScene in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, skscene

I am making a game, and I want to present a `UIView` (for my Share Scene in my game), from my `MenuScene.swift` (which is a SKScene) file.  I've searched on Stack Overflow for similar questions, but none of them worked in my game. Can anyone show me how it's done?

Menu Scene:

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {   
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 62/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1.0)
        addLabelsAndButtons()
    }

    func addLabelsAndButton() {

        let shareButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ShareButton")
        shareButton.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.height/12, height: frame.size.height/12)
        shareButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + shareButton.size.width/1.5, y: frame.minY + shareButton.size.height)
        shareButton.name = "ShareButton"
        addChild(shareButton)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if atPoint((touch.location(in: self))).name == "ShareButton" {
            //Where I want to present my Share Scene!
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot present a UIView inside an SKScene, as SKScene has been optimised to handle sprite rendering for games and uses a different technology stack from UIView.

What you can do is add a UIView to the parent view that the SKView was added to (which is also a UIView). This allows you to present a more static view overplayed on top of your game's sprite view, for example: a score view, hud view or a menu.

I've put a diagram of this below:

```
UIView
  ⮑ 0: SKView
          ⮑ 0: SKScene
  ⮑ 1: UIView
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! I would try my best to do what you said right now!

Comment: But I mean that when the share button is pressed in the MenuScene, it would present a UIView (Of the Share UIView). But I don't know how to do the transition between them. Is there a way? I've seen a lot of similar situations on Stack Overflow, but none of them worked in my game.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a delegate setup or use a notification to comunícate your intent to the UI layer.